# Use Cases for Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark

We have an application which the clients use to track their procurement cycle. We need to build a solution which will help the users to pull any column from any table in a particular subject area and they should be able to see all the rows of the result of this join of the tables from which the columns have been pulled. It needs to be similar to a Salesforce kind of reporting solution. We are looking at HDFS and Spark in Azure HDInsight to support these kind of querying capabilities. We would like to know if this is a valid use case for Spark. The volume of the joins of all tables can easily touch 500 million rows which will be pulled into the Spark driver memory before being displayed to the user.

Please let me know if this is something that can be done using Spark.

Comment: Need Some More Explanation About Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, Spark is mostly used for batch processing. If your use case is directly user-facing, then I am doubtful about using Spark because there may be better solutions(or alternate architectures). Becuase joining 500 million rows in realtime sounds crazy!

> The volume of the joins of all tables can easily touch 500 million rows which will be pulled into the Spark driver memory before being displayed to the user.

This is another thing that puzzled me. Pulling all the 500 million rows into RAM of a single java process doesn't sound right because of the obvious reasons.

**Updated**

Just using spark for processing huge data will not be effective for realtime solutions(like your use case). But, Spark will be very effective if you are going to pre-process your data, cache the results using some other system, prepare views using the results can be served to your users. More or less similar to **Lambda Architecture**.

**Spark on Yarn cluster** to periodically process the data and generate/update the different views, a **distributed storage system** (preferably columnar storage systems) to cache the views, a **REST API** to serve the views to users.

Comment: Basically, we need to build a real time operational reporting solution which can perform aggregations, roll-up, drill-down and slice and dice like any other multi-dimensional cube solution but it needs to be real time.

Comment: Just using spark for processing huge data will not be effective for realtime solutions(like your use case). But, Spark will be very effective if you are going to pre-process your data, cache the results using some other system, prepare views using the results can be served to your users. More or less similar to Lambda Architecture.

Comment: Let me know if this was helpful, I'll update my answer likewise.

Comment: Thanks! This does help but if you have seen this requirement before what stack will you suggest we look at?

Comment: I don't have any hands-on experience with such a system as a whole. Based on experience with individual tools, I would say Spark on Yarn for batch processing, any storages like Cassandra/HBase/Parquet for storing the processed results, and API to serve the views from the storage should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply to the question, but in case someone else is reading this in future. AWS Redshift does exactly this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).